# Recieving PHP Warning copy(): Filename cannot be empty

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins, copy

I am receiving this warning in one of the Wordpress plugins.

> **copy(): Filename cannot be empty** in /wp-content/plugins/nix-gravatar-cache/nf-gravatar-cache.php on line 181

Please help me correct this, if somebody can. I am not very good with PHP. Thanks

Here is the code.

```
<?php

class NFGC_Gravatar_Cache {

    protected $upload_url;
    protected $upload_path;
    protected $plugin_dir_path;

    public $plugin_name = 'NIX Gravatar Cache';

    function __construct(){
        if ( get_option( 'upload_url_path' ) ) {
            $this->upload_url  = get_option( 'upload_url_path' );
            $this->upload_path = get_option( 'upload_path' );
        }
        else {
            $up_dir = wp_upload_dir();

            $this->upload_url  = $up_dir['baseurl'];
            $this->upload_path = $up_dir['basedir'];
        }

        $this->plugin_dir_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ );

        require_once $this->plugin_dir_path . '/messages.class.php';
        NFGC_Messages::init();

        $active = get_option( 'nf_c_a_options' );
        if ( $active[0]['active'] == 1 ) {
            add_filter( 'get_avatar', array( $this,'get_cached_avatar' ), -1000000000, 5 );
        }

        add_action( 'admin_menu', array( $this,'add_admin_menu' ) );
        register_activation_hook( __FILE__, array( $this, 'activate' )  );
        $this->init();

        register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'deactivate' );
        register_uninstall_hook( __FILE__ , 'uninstall' );

        if ( !is_writable( $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/' ) && is_dir( $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/' ) ) {
            NFGC_Messages::add_message( 'error', 'Please set write permissions for "'. $this->upload_path .'/gravatar/"' );
        }else{
            if ( @!mkdir( $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/', 0777 ) && ! is_dir( $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/' ) ) {
                NFGC_Messages::add_message( 'error', 'Could not create directory "gravatar". Please set write permissions for "'. $this->upload_path .'/gravatar/"'  );
            }
        }

        if ( isset ( $_POST['nf_clear_cache'] ) )
            $this->clear_cache();

    }

    public function get_template_path() {
        return $this->plugin_dir_path .'template';
    }

    // Activate plugin and update default option
    public function activate() {

        $dir = $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/';

        // delete_option('nf_c_a_options');
        if ( get_option( 'nf_c_a_options' ) == false ) {
            $default_options = array('active'   => 1,
                                     'ttl_day'  => 10,
                                     'ttl_hour' => 0,
                                     'ttl_min'  => 0
                                    );
            update_option( 'nf_c_a_options', array( $default_options ) );
        }

    }

    // Deactivate plugin and clear cache
    public function deactivate() {

        $this->clear_cache();

    }

    // Notice in plugin options page
    public function admin_help_notice() {
        global $current_screen;
        if ( $current_screen->base == 'settings_page_'. basename( __FILE__,'.php' ) ) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    // convert ttl option to second
    private function cache_to_second(){
        $cache_time = get_option( 'nf_c_a_options' );
        $cache_time = array_reverse( $cache_time[0] );

        $action = array();
        foreach ( $cache_time as $key => $value ) {
            if ( $key == 'active' )
                continue;

            switch ( $key ) {
                case 'ttl_min':
                    $cache_second = $value != 0 ? $value*60 : '';
                    break;
                case 'ttl_hour':
                    $cache_second = $value != 0 ? ( $value*60*60 ) + $cache_second : $cache_second;
                    break;
                case 'ttl_day':
                    $cache_second = $value != 0 ? ( $value*60*60*24 ) + $cache_second : $cache_second;
                    break;
            }

        }

        if ( ! $cache_second ) {
            $cache_second = 864000;// TTL of cache in seconds (10 days)

        }

        return $cache_second;
    }

    // The main functional
    public function get_cached_avatar( $source, $id_or_email, $size, $default, $alt ) {

        if ( !is_writable( $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/' ) || is_admin() ) {
            return $source;
        }
        $time = $this->cache_to_second();

        preg_match('/d=([^&]*)/', $source, $d_tmp);
        $g_url_default_sorce = isset($d_tmp[1]) ? $d_tmp[1] : false;

        preg_match('/forcedefault=([^&]*)/', $source, $d_tmp);
        $g_forcedefault = isset($d_tmp[1]) ? $d_tmp[1] : false;

        preg_match('/avatar\/([a-z0-9]+)\?s=(\d+)/', $source, $tmp);
        $garvatar_id = $tmp[1];

        $file_name      = md5($garvatar_id.$g_url_default_sorce);
        $g_path         = $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/'.$file_name.'-s'.$size.'.jpg';
      //* $g_path_default = $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/default'.'-s'.$size.'.jpg';
        $g_url          = $this->upload_url.'/gravatar/'.$file_name.'-s'.$size.'.jpg';
      //* $g_url_default  = $this->upload_url.'/gravatar/'.'default'.'-s'.$size.'.jpg';

        // Check cache
        static $nf_avatars_cache = null;
        if ($nf_avatars_cache === null)    $nf_avatars_cache = get_option('nf_avatars_cache');
        if (! is_array($nf_avatars_cache)) $nf_avatars_cache = array();

        if (isset($nf_avatars_cache[$garvatar_id][$size])) {
            $g_url  = $nf_avatars_cache[$garvatar_id][$size]['url'];
            $g_path = $nf_avatars_cache[$garvatar_id][$size]['path'];
        }

        if (! is_file($g_path) || (time()-filemtime($g_path)) > $time) {
            $curl_url = 'https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/'.$garvatar_id.'?s='.$size.'&r=G&d='.$g_url_default_sorce;

            $ch = curl_init($curl_url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
            $response    = curl_exec($ch);
            $header_size = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_SIZE);
            $header      = substr($response, 0, $header_size);

            // Checking for redirect
            $header_array = array();
            preg_match('/^Location\: (.*)$/m', $header, $header_array);
            $redirect_url = isset($header_array[1]) ? $header_array[1] : false;

            if ($redirect_url) {
                $g_url  = $g_url_default;
                $g_path = $g_path_default;
                if (! is_file($g_path) || (time()-filemtime($g_path)) > $time) {
                    copy($redirect_url, $g_path);
                }
            }
            else {
                // Check mime type
                $mime_str   = curl_getinfo( $ch, CURLINFO_CONTENT_TYPE );
                $mime_array = array();
                preg_match( '#/([a-z]*)#i', $mime_str, $mime_array );

                if (isset($mime_array[1])) {
                    // Write cache to file
                    $fp   = fopen( $g_path, "wb" );
                    $body = substr( $response, $header_size );
                    fwrite( $fp, $body );
                    fclose( $fp );
                }
            }
            curl_close($ch);

            $nf_avatars_cache[$garvatar_id][$size]['url']  = $g_url;
            $nf_avatars_cache[$garvatar_id][$size]['path'] = $g_path;
            update_option( 'nf_avatars_cache', $nf_avatars_cache );
        }

        return '<img alt = "'.$alt.'" src=\''.$g_url.'\' class="avatar avatar-'.$size.'" width="'.$size.'" height="'.$size.'" />';
    }

    // Create plugin option settings menu
    public function add_admin_menu() {
        // settings menu page
       add_options_page( 'Cached Avatar ', $this->plugin_name, 'manage_options', basename( __FILE__ ), array( $this,'view_options_page' ) );
    }

    // Create page option
    public function view_options_page() {
        // update options

        if ( isset( $_POST['nf_c_a_submit'] ) ) {
            $update_val_options = $_POST['nf_c_a_options'];

            foreach ( $update_val_options as $option => $value ) {
                $update_val_options[$option] = abs( intval( $value ) );
            }

            if( $update_val_options['ttl_min'] == 0 && $update_val_options['ttl_hour'] == 0 && $update_val_options['ttl_day'] == 0 ) {
                $update_val_options['ttl_day'] = 10;
            }

            update_option( 'nf_c_a_options', array( $update_val_options ) );

        }

        $options = get_option( 'nf_c_a_options' );

        include( $this->get_template_path() .'/main-options-page.php');
    }

    private function clear_cache() {
        $dir = $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/';
        $no_permision_to_delete = false;

        // Open directory
        if ( is_dir( $dir ) ) {
            if ( $opendir = opendir( $dir ) ) {
                $count = 0;
                while ( ( $file = readdir( $opendir ) ) !== false ) {
                    if ( filetype( $dir . $file ) == 'file' ) {
                        if ( @unlink( $dir . $file ) ) {
                            $count++;
                        }else {
                            $no_permision_to_delete = true;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if ( $no_permision_to_delete ) {
                    NFGC_Messages::add_message( 'error','Unable to clear the cache' );
                }else{
                    update_option('nf_avatars_cache', array() );
                    NFGC_Messages::add_message( 'info','The cache is cleared!' );
                    NFGC_Messages::add_message( 'info','Removed '.$count.' files' );
                }
                closedir( $opendir );
            }
        }
   }

    // return count and size
    public function get_cache_info() {
        $dir  = $this->upload_path.'/gravatar/';
        $skip = array('.','..');
        $unit = array('b', 'kb', 'mb', 'gb', 'tb', 'pb');

        if ( is_dir( $dir ) ) {
           $file_list = scandir( $dir );

           // delete . and ..
           foreach ( $skip as $value ) {
               unset( $file_list[ array_search( $value, $file_list ) ] );
           }

           // sum files size
           foreach ( $file_list as $file ) {
               $size     = filesize( $dir . $file );
               $all_size = $all_size + $size;
           }
        }

        $readable_form = @round( $all_size / pow( 1024, ( $i = floor( log( $all_size, 1024) ) ) ), 2 ) . ' ' . $unit[$i];

        return array( 'amount' => count( $file_list ) , 'used_space' => $readable_form );
   }

    private function init() {
        return false;
        wp_enqueue_script( 'nfgc-main-script', plugins_url( '/js/main.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
        wp_enqueue_style( 'nfgc-main-style', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
   }

}// Class

global $nfgc;
$nfgc = new NFGC_Gravatar_Cache();
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', function() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'nfgc-main-script', plugins_url( '/js/main.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery') );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'nfgc-main-style', plugins_url( '/css/style.css', __FILE__ ) );
});
```

`

Comment: One point to note, if you make a change to this file and then you update the plugin at some point, if the developer has not fixed this issue, you will find that your change will be overwritten by the developer's update. You can see that this developer is not doing checks for some things which is evident when they put an `@` symbol in front of functions to suppress warnings as in `@round()` or  `@unlink()`. I don't know if this error is a fatal error, but if not, you could easily follow suit with `@copy($redirect_url, $g_path);` since any updates will wipe your change(s) anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

Use `file_exists`

Returns TRUE if the file or directory specified by filename exists; FALSE otherwise.

```
if (file_exists($redirect_url)) {
                $g_url  = $g_url_default;
                $g_path = $g_path_default;
                if (! is_file($g_path) || (time()-filemtime($g_path)) > $time) {
                    copy($redirect_url, $g_path);
                }
            }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php